Convention to indicate the base-10 logarithmic scale of a graphic's axis
Is there any specific convention on how to indicate that the scale I use on a graphic's axis is a base-10 logarithmic scale?
For example, if we consider the $x$-axis, can I write something like this in a text?

In Figure 1, we use $log_{10}(x\text{-axis})$.

